# Copying .csv file located on Heroku server to local drive

Tags: python, django, heroku-cli

I have a Python/Django web application deployed to Heroku that writes information to a .csv file.

Once the file has been written I want to pull it down from the Heroku server to the users local drive.

I don't need to persist the file anywhere and so I am avoiding using S3 or storing in the database.

I have used the Heroku "ps:copy" command which works but surely this would mean the user would need the Heroku CLI installed on their machine for this to work?

Is there any other way?

Comment: Why can't you just let the user download the file without saving it?

Comment: The user would presumably need both the Heroku CLI AND your credentials to your server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want them to be able to do, just download file immediately after it is created on server/dyno.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to generate a temporary link, generate the file, download immediately, and then delete the file?

Comment: Yes it would except the delete part. The file persists on the Dyno until restart of Dyno or the app sleeps due to inactivity (Free Heroku account). This is long enough for what it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. When sent to the csv_view, Django generates a CSV and has it automatically download to the client's browser.

Your provided code:

```
# Generate report filename
filename = djqscsv.generate_filename(qs, append_datestamp=True)

# Generate report
try:
    with open(filename, 'ab') as csv_file:
        print(filename)
        write_csv(qs, csv_file)
        messages.success(request, 'Consultation added to report successfully!')
        messages.warning(request, 'Note: Certain needs may not appear in report, \
                                         this is a result of filtering process.')
```

You need to merge this code with my code into the same view.

```
def csv_view(request):
    filename =  djqscsv.generate_filename(qs, append_datestamp=True)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.csv"',format(filename)
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(qs) #use a for loop if you have multiple rows
    messages.success(request, 'Consultation added to report successfully!')
    messages.warning(request, 'Note: Certain needs may not appear in report, \
                                         this is a result of filtering process.')

    return response
```

Just to be clear, `csv_view` is where the CSV is generated, not merely a link to the CSV generated in another view.

This method does not save the CSV to the Dyno either. I thought that it did and just deleted it after, but I don't think it saves it to the server ever.

Comment: No problem. If this answer resolved your issue, click the checkmark to the right of my answer so that everyone knows that this issue is done with.

Comment: Tried it but it just renders text in the browser. Using Safari, tried using Chrome but got an ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION error (which is resolvable but not attempted this yet.

Comment: How are you doing the request?

Comment: t = (request.user.username)
qs = Need.objects.filter(user_id=t)

Comment: Managed to implement your code suggestion with a couple of changes and it works well. However, is it possible to return the response that initiates the download of the csv file AND then redirect to home?

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted the code below that currently generates the .csv using the djqscsv library that works with Django QuerySets:

```
# Generate report filename
filename = djqscsv.generate_filename(qs, append_datestamp=True)

# Generate report
try:
    with open(filename, 'ab') as csv_file:
        print(filename)
        write_csv(qs, csv_file)
        messages.success(request, 'Consultation added to report successfully!')
        messages.warning(request, 'Note: Certain needs may not appear in report, \
                                         this is a result of filtering process.')
```

So once "csv_file" has been written I would then redirect to the "csv_view" you have described above, obviously without writing any further rows?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the djqscsv library has the render_to_csv_response included which solves the problem:

```
# Generate file name from QuerySet
filename =  djqscsv.generate_filename(qs, append_datestamp=True)

# Autodownload csv file in browser
return render_to_csv_response(qs, filename=filename)
```